# @font face not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to get my font working in firefox, seems to work fine in IE, chrome and Safari

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
 font-family: MyCustomFont;
 src: url("http://www.brightonorient.com/MTCORSVA.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
 font-family: MyCustomFont;
 src: url("http://www.brightonorient.com/MTCORSVA.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}

</style>
```

This is the website here, http://www.brightonorient.com - the front page text Brighton Orient should be Monotype corsiva.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

Answer (score 1):

I typically use Font Squirrel for my @font-face needs and have never had an issue. Check [this link](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems) to see if the trouble shooting tips provide any help. If it is any consolation, in Firefox on my machine I can see the font load just fine and render properly. Throwing FireBug on it shows the font loaded properly as well. Not sure why you're not seeing it work unless your Firefox is not up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, for some reason Font Squirrel wouldn't let me use that font but its all working now just needed to change the css.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it works for me on WinXP SP3 with Fx 6.0.2 but not with Fx 11.0

Though, on the legal side (IANAL), it seems you don't have the rights to use Monotype Corsiva with @font-face: only Monotype does. See http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=172339 and their service http://webfonts.fonts.com for maybe a solution.
Using it on your computer and distributing it to every visitor via your server are often two very different licences!

Answer (score 0):

go to this link http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

upload your font

then download all files have different font formats which is supported for different browsers
and use in your project. now it will work accurately in all browsers